# Look behind does not work to exclude a word

Tags: regex, pcre

In the following example text I am trying to write a regex to match `token`, `password` , …  but not `items`. I tried to use `\'(<?items)(.*)\' => \[` without any success. What is the correct RegEx to do that?

```
    [
        'items' => [
            'token' => [
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'ng-model' => 'token'
            ],
            'password' => [
                'readonly' => $token,
                'type' => 'password',
            ],
            'newPassword' => [
                'type' => 'password'
            ],
            'confirmPassword' => [
                'type' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

### Update

I wonder why `.*(?!items)`, `.*(?<!items)` , `(?<=itmes).*` and `(?!items).*` do not work functionally the same in this particular situation?

Comment: Why bother with regex when you can simply use `strpos` or something of that nature. Regex seems a bit of an overkill as long as you're matching exact words.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nA6tP6/1 you're using the wrong regex. see the link. You need ?! not <?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? do you want the values that do not have item as key in this array?

Comment: That is a valid PHP array data structure already – so why not let PHP parse it, and then operate on the data structure, instead of doing string manipulation using regex …?

Comment: @Terminus Thanks, that works. I also update the question.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vY8aR1/1 more interesting(?) results. But yea, what CBroe said

Comment: No idea why my comment was removed when setting the question as a dupe. If Terminus' regex works for you, this post is a duplicate. A negative lookahead works as well here. If you are not confident in regex, avoid using it when it is redundant (as is the case here). If you want to study it, I recommend [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Answer (score 2):

A **negative** lookahead should be applied at focus position (after ' char):

```
\'(?!items\')(.*)\' => \[
```